# Adjusting the number of years in a range of values per group in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to correct some typing errors in my database. These errors pertain to the 'number of years' variable. For instance, for ID 1, in 2005, the 'number of years' variable was recorded as 18. In this scenario, the correct value for the 'number of years' variable in 2008 would be 21, and in 2009, it should be 22, and so forth for subsequent years. The same logic applies to other IDs.

However, there are some age-related typing errors scattered throughout the database. I believe these errors can be rectified by cross-referencing the 'Period' and 'Number of years' variables, considering the sequential order of these variables. I attempted various methods, but unfortunately, none of them were successful.

In practical terms, I need to transform, for example:

[image]

In something like:

[image]

Here is a reproducible example of the data with the errors:

```
structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 
4, 4, 4), Period = c(2005, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2007, 2015, 2016, 
2017, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2007, 2009, 2010, 2011), Value = c(18, 
71, 22, 23, 27, 35, 76, 37, 30, 31, 32, 83, 88, 20, 21, 62)), row.names = c(NA, 
16L), class = "data.frame")
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An answer with *data.table*:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)
dat[,
    Value := {
        idx <- which(c(diff(Period) == diff(Value), FALSE))[1]
        Value[idx] + Period - Period[idx]
    },
    by=id]
dat
##    id Period Value
## 1:  1   2005    18
## 2:  1   2008    21
## 3:  1   2009    22
## 4:  1   2010    23
## 5:  2   2007    27
## 6:  2   2015    35
## 7:  2   2016    36
## 8:  2   2017    37
## 9:  3   2014    30
##10:  3   2015    31
##11:  3   2016    32
##12:  3   2017    33
##13:  4   2007    18
##14:  4   2009    20
##15:  4   2010    21
##16:  4   2011    22
```

This relies on finding a pair of rows where the difference between `Period` and `Value` are in sync, flagging this as a 'true' row, then recalculating all the values based on this row.

Answer (score 2):

A `data.table` approach that, for each `id`, uses `table` and `which.max` to build a "consensus" on the value of `Period` at `Value = 0`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[
  ,Value := {
    p0 <- table(Period - Value)
    Period - as(names(p0[which.max(p0)]), typeof(Period))
  },
  id
][]
#>     id Period Value
#>  1:  1   2005    18
#>  2:  1   2008    21
#>  3:  1   2009    22
#>  4:  1   2010    23
#>  5:  2   2007    27
#>  6:  2   2015    35
#>  7:  2   2016    36
#>  8:  2   2017    37
#>  9:  3   2014    30
#> 10:  3   2015    31
#> 11:  3   2016    32
#> 12:  3   2017    33
#> 13:  4   2007    18
#> 14:  4   2009    20
#> 15:  4   2010    21
#> 16:  4   2011    22
```